# Mean Square of Regression Error for categorical variables while computing F statistic

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, regression-coefficients, degrees-of-freedom, f-statistic

Give the annova table in the image below:

[image]

I need to calculate the F statistic for the null hypothesis: b2 = b3 = 0 .
b2 is cofficient of cylinder and b3 is the coefficient of doors. The formula used is.

> F stat = (SSR/(Degree of freedom))/Mean square error

The SSR or Sum of Squared Regression Error in this case should be 36091021540+297072781. 
I also have the Mean square error figured out which is 43063112.

However, am not so sure about the degree of freedom in this case. Should it be 2+1 = 3 i.e sum of dof of individual coefficients, or should it be just 2 since there are two coefficients that we are testing against?

Comment: Based on the output, cylinder has 3 levels and 2 $\beta$s. Maybe both $\beta_2$ and $\beta_3$ are for cylinder.

Comment: @user158565 Sorry, to clarify b2 here is for cylinder and b3 is for doors. There is no doubt about that since them being 0 or not is what I want to F-test.

Comment: df = 2 for cylinder = cylinder has 3 levels and 2 βs. If you insist that b2 here is for cylinder, then which one? Even you can specify which, it is impossible to test it based on the information you have.

Comment: @user158565 I get you now. You were spot on with the interpretation. b2 and b3 do correspond to the different level of cylinder. So, the degree of freedom would then be 2. Thanks :)